# android overlay activity issue

Tags: android, touch, overlay

I have an activity that creates a view of type `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` and I set a touch listener to the view. Is it possible to record the touch but still send the touch event to other views (example: to a widget from my home screen)?

Here is my code:

```
public class TestGestures extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams param=new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        param.flags=WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
        final View view=findViewById(R.id.view1);
        final ViewGroup parent=(ViewGroup)view.getParent();
        if(parent!=null)
            parent.removeView(view);
        param.format= PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
        param.type=WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
        param.gravity= Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT;
        param.width=view.getLayoutParams().width;
        param.height=view.getLayoutParams().height;
        //view.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.white);
        final WindowManager wmgr=(WindowManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wmgr.addView(view,param);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I'm in the home screen, the touch events are not sent to the widgets

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to play around with the parameters that you're using to setup your `WindowManager.LayoutParams`. For example, the code below will make the touch events be delivered to the Activity (or View) which is below the view that you just created:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

On the other hand, if you change `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` to `TYPE_SYSTEM_PHONE`, the input events will be delivered to the View that is on top of the other ones:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

So, in your case, since you want the input events to be delivered to the views below, try setting the `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` flag.

Comment: iF i USE TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, onTouch method from my activity it's not called at all so I cannot get touches. My purpose is to get touches, but this touches to be sent to the views bellow